# PHP 4 how to strip a specific variable from the URL

Tags: php, php4

PHP 4  how to strip a specific variable from the URL in this case "?lang=en"

/filename.php?lang=en

Comment: Using PHP4 on production is quite suicidal these days I am afraid...

Comment: what do you want the output to be if the url is `/filename.php?lang=en`? Also, would the output you require be different if the url was `/filename.php?lang=en&foo=bar`?

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = '/filename.php?lang=en&test=1';                    // the main link
$str = parse_url($url);                                   // parse_url
parse_str($str['query'], $arr);                           // parse_str on 'query'
unset($arr['lang']);                                      // unset 'lang'
$newQuery = http_build_query($arr);                       // rebuild query
$link = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '?')).'?'.$newQuery; // remake link

echo $link; // /filename.php?test=1
```

This can be easily wrapped up into a function:

```
function removeParameter($link, $remove){
    $str = parse_url($link);                                    // parse_url on $link
    parse_str($str['query'], $arr);                             // parse_str on 'query'
    unset($arr[$remove]);                                       // unset $remove
    $newQuery = http_build_query($arr);                         // rebuild query
    $link = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, '?')).'?'.$newQuery; // remake link
    return $link;
}

echo removeParameter('/filename.php?lang=en&test=1', 'lang'); // /filename.php?test=1
echo removeParameter('http://www.example.com/filename.php?lang=en&test=1&me=do', 'test'); // http://www.example.com/filename.php?lang=en&me=do
```

Answer (score 0):

You are look for the [super global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) $_GET:

```
echo $_GET['lang']; // will put 'en' on the screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/substr) and [strrpos()](http://php.net/strrpos);

```
$str = 'filename.php?lang=en';
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '?'));
echo $str; // Outputs 'filename.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `preg_match('/^([^?]+)/', '/filename.php?lang=en')` to match everything up until the question mark.